# Groovy: ArrayList each is not working

Tags: groovy

It does not make sense but this groovy is behaving absurd.
Code is like this:

```
def xmlArray = xmlMap['ClientXml'] //Map has key and array of xml for each key.

println "Length of Array"
println xmlArray.length //prints [, ,]
println xmlArray.size() //prints 3
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xmlArray[1] ) //prints xml
println xmlArray.getClass().name //prints java.util.ArrayList

//This part does not work
xmlArray.each {
  println it
}
```

Not sure what got changed in my code but it was workng fine before.

Comment: I bet `println xmlArray.getClass().name` shows you it's not a list

Comment: @tim_yates `xmlArray.getClass().name` gives me `java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: can you be more specific about "This part does not work". What behavior do you see?

Comment: @codelark Flow skips `each` part and does not print anything.

Comment: What about `println xmlArray.collect { XmlUtil.serialize( it ) }`

Comment: And are you sure it's not just printing 3 blank lines?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing right now.  I printed out the class name, and it's java.util.ArrayList, yet when I try to iterate using each, it gets treated like a single object, rather than an iterated collection.  @HimanshuYadav, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Seeing the same behavior, even when changing it to `array.each { println("test") }`

Answer (score 1):

I have no deeper insight to offer except that rewriting the loop as `for (element in array) { ... }` was a sufficent solution for me (and I usually prefer that notation anyway)...